# Google Places Autocomplete (ngx-google-places-autocomplete) is not working in Angular 16

Tags: angular16, ngx-google-places-autocomplete

After upgrading to Angular 16, the "ngx-google-places-autocomplete" does not work any more.

There are the next error

```
main.ts:29 Unhandled Promise rejection: GooglePlaceModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property) ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: GooglePlaceModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property)
```

Here is the code of integration

```
import { GooglePlaceModule } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [..., GooglePlaceModule],
  providers: [...]
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Does someone have a recipe to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package is currently not supported for Angular 16 version. Please consider using alternatives that are fully compatible with `ngx-google-places-autocomplete`

You can try:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-magic/ngx-gp-autocomplete

**[Reference](https://github.com/skynet2/ngx-google-places-autocomplete/issues/118)**